# Should you adjust predicted probabilites when evaluating feature calibration when you have a prediction problem

Tags: machine-learning, r-squared, calibration

I am testing different ways to estimate the calibration of of machine learning models (binary classifiers, both during training and once it is in production). The problem I have come across is how to handle when you have a general prediction error (in production).

For example:
I have a model predicting probabilities. My average prediction is 50% but the observerd outcome is 60%. If you look at feature 1 it looks very well calibrated besides the fact that the model is a factor 1.2 off in its predictions. Feature 2 seems to be worse calibrated. However if I use some sort of metric that measures how much error I have (for exaple R2) many will say the the error is the same on both features.

I could multiply all my predicted probabilites with 1.2 to adjust for the general error. If I do this the metrics will clearly be able to differentiate calibration level. The assumption then is that the general error is at the same level for each bucket when bucketing a certain feature.

Is it ok to make this assumption?
Is there some other way to approach the problem?

[image: Calibration]

EDIT:
What I mean with lookin at calibration for a certain feature whether or not it was included in the model.

Imagine you have a model trying to predict the probability that a customer wants to purchase a certain product. Included in the model is gender, social status, income, number of recent purchases (as an example). You have a bunch of different other potential features that you did not include for example, age, height, star sign.

You could then bin predictions on age, 10-20, 20-30... in each bucket you will have a predicted probability and an observed probability. If the predicted probability in these bucket differs a lot from the observed probabilities you could conclude that there is some information in age that you were missing and that for some reason did not come through when you trained your model.

Comment: Are you using two separate models, one with Feature 1 and one with Feature 2? It looks like you are not using a single model that leverages both features. If so, why not? That said, there is the concept of "recalibrating" probabilistic predictions, essentially by feeding the predictions (potentially spline-transformed) into a logistic regression or similar, and the predictions from that second model should be better calibrated.

Comment: It is the same model but I the features might not be included in the model. I want to evaluate the model on all dimensions of the data even those that were not included as a feature to the model.

Comment: I think I'm not quite understanding. How do you assess whether a specific *feature* is well calibrated? Calibration is an attribute of *predictions*, i.e., of a *model*. This is why it sounds to me like you have two different models.

Comment: Stephan, I made an edit trying to explain what I mean.

Comment: So your top left plot is a calibration plot of your model with Feature 1 removed? And the top right plot is a calibration plot of the model with Feature 2 removed?

Comment: What the OP described is miscalibration-in-the-large.  If you can't get calibration-in-the-large right you should question the whole approach.  It is not usually a good idea to apply a fudge factor such as 1.2 to the predictions as then you have no way to validate the fudged predictions.  Instead use a method that controls overfitting.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I totally agree with regards to building the model. The question I have is with regards to a model in production that is misaligned and trying to figure out why. I have edited my question to specify this.

Comment: It is not correct to use binning when assessing calibration.  A calibration curve is smooth and often nonlinear.  Calibration is not something you assess for a feature but rather for the whole model.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I have edited my question to reflect that it is mostly binary classifiers that I am interested in. In order to evaluate the calibration of these I bin in different dimension to compare predict_proba with the observed outcome.

Comment: For continuous predictors and continuous predictors binning is not valid.